# Django - Permissions and DeleteView, is this a good way to do it?

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-class-based-views

Hi so I have a working view. I wanted to know if this is the best or a good way of doing it. I want to have a delete view that deletes a Photo object but only if the logged in user is the on associated with the object.

Here is my views.py

```
class PhotoDelete(DeleteView):
    model = Photo
    template_name = 'otologue/photo_delete.html'
    success_url = reverse_lazy('otologue:photos')

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        object_instance = self.get_object()  # Get the object
        object_user = object_instance.photoextended.user  # Get the user who owns the object

        user = get_object_or_404(User, username=self.request.user)  # Get the user in the view
        if object_user != user:  # See if the object_user is the same as the user
            return HttpResponseForbidden('Permission Error')
        else:
            return render(request, self.template_name, {'object': object_instance})

    @method_decorator(login_required)
    def dispatch(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return super().dispatch(*args, **kwargs)
```

If you need more info like the models and such, please request it.

Answer (score 0):

- You don't have to call `get_object_or_404()`, since `self.request.user` already contains an instance of User, so you can compare it directly.
- You should call (and return the result) DeleteView's `get()` method instead of rendering the template yourself.
- I would also use `LoginRequiredMixin` instead of a decorator, since your `dispatch()` now does nothing apart from calling super's method.
- Be aware, that the actual deletion is done in the `post()` method. You should move your user check to the `dispatch()` method, otherwise it will be possible to bypass the check with a forged POST request.

To have better idea what DeleteView does in its methods, check it's source code (for example at [ccbv.co.uk](https://ccbv.co.uk/projects/Django/1.10/django.views.generic.edit/DeleteView/))

Comment: With `DeleteView` I have an issue on using `LoginRequiredMixin`. While in other Views it is working, in case od DeleteView it runs `dispatch` anyway (in POST and GET).